# How to select Dynamic column from List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select columns dynamically from `List` as following. So what could be the best way?

```
//a objects list
List<DashBoard> dashboardlist = (List<DashBoard>)objList;  
string strColumns = "RecDate,ModifiedDate";
objList = (from obj in dashboardlist select new { strColumns }).ToList();
```

/////////////
Ok,Just forget Object List say I have database table which have number of column ID,Name,Age,sex,etc ..Then I have columnList to display and the columnList  is change according to condition .   SO I have List people; and List columnTemplate; so now I want to select the column based on the  template .

Comment: How do you plan on using `objList`?  I hope you realize it won't be as simple to access the properties as when you statically define the columns (`select new { obj.RecDate, obj.ModifiedDate }`) you're selecting so C# can create an anonymous type for you.  It might be easier to simply keep using the full `DashBoard` objects and only read the properties specified by the strings as needed.

Comment: What is the situation that has brought up this question? I'd be inclined to agree with Tim S - stick with the Dashboard object

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to return an anonymous object or what you need is to return a `List<Dashboard>` with different properties initialized?

Comment: Ok,Just forget Object List say I have database table which have number of column ID,Name,Age,sex,etc ..Then I have columnList to display and the columnList  is change according to condition .   SO I have List<Person> people; and List<string> columnTeamlte; so now I want to select the column based on the  template .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for providing ideas to my question.Spending couple of hours in 
 Google  I found [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/141367/Dynamic-Columns-from-List-using-LINQ) .

```
public void Test() {
    var data = new[] {
        new TestData { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 }
    ,   new TestData { X = 2, Y = 4, Z = 6 }
    };
    var strColumns = "X,Z".Split(',');
    foreach (var item in data.Select(a => Projection(a, strColumns))) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.X, item.Z);
    }
}
private static dynamic Projection(object a, IEnumerable<string> props) {
    if (a == null) {
        return null;
    }
    IDictionary<string,object> res = new ExpandoObject();
    var type = a.GetType();
    foreach (var pair in props.Select(n => new {
        Name = n
    ,   Property = type.GetProperty(n)})) {
        res[pair.Name] = pair.Property.GetValue(a, new object[0]);
    }
    return res;
}
class TestData {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the list of the columns may come from an external resource and change, I propose:

With reflection you could produce a list of FieldInfo that correspond to each Column, then loop over each item on the list and each FieldInfo and call GetValue on the data object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
[Select a Column Dynamically using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717039/select-a-column-dynamically-using-linq)
and look Dynamic Linq: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let's supposed that you have only 2 templates. You can create a method for each template, that returns only the columns you need. Something like this:

```
// method for template 1 - returns only 3 columns/properties
private DashBoard CreateDashBoardXxxxxxx(DashBoard item)
{
    return new DashBoard {
        Property1 = item.Property1,
        Property4 = item.Property2,
        Property3 = item.Property3
    };
}

// method for template 2 - returns N columns/properties
private DashBoard CreateDashBoardYyyyyyyy(DashBoard item)
{
    return new DashBoard {
        Property1 = item.Property1,
        Property4 = item.Property2,

        // Other properties
        // .....

        PropertyN = item.PropertyN
    };
}
```

You can then use those methods like this:

```
List<DashBoard> dashboardlist = (List<DashBoard>)objList; 

// using template 1
var list = dashboardlist.Select(CreateDashBoardXxxxxxx);

// using template 2
var list2 = dashboardlist.Select(CreateDashBoardYyyyyyyy);
```

You just need to do some code to decide which template should be used.

I hope this helps!!